# Crash OutOfMemory Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap when using Glide 4 to show image with transition crossFade

Tags: android, android-glide, android-transitions

I am using GlideApp for loading images in a slide images, this problem is when I load a lot of images, transition is changed continuity and it gives to me one crash  *Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@71167b3*

I try to find a way to fix it but hopeless.

I believe that crash occur because of **placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())**
and AS my expected is transition cross from old image to new image so I have to use placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())

Could you guys have anyway to fix them? Thanks so much!

```
  public void loadImageWithFade(final ImageView imageView, final String url) {
        if (imageView == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        GlideApp.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .transition(new DrawableTransitionOptions().crossFade(FADE_DURATION_MS))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After time to looking for. I found one solution and it's working to me

```
    public static final int FULLY_VISIBLE = 1;
    private static final int FADE_DURATION_MS = 500;
    public static final float ALMOST_TRANSPARENT = 0.2f;
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static Runnable runnable;
 public static void loadImageWithFade(final ImageView imageView, final String url) {
        if (imageView == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Using new feature and upgrade glide to 4

        GlideApp.with(imageView.getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        if (!resource.isRecycled()) {
                            animateView(imageView, FULLY_VISIBLE, ALMOST_TRANSPARENT);
                            if (runnable != null) {
                                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            }
                            runnable = () -> {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                                animateView(imageView, ALMOST_TRANSPARENT, FULLY_VISIBLE);
                            };
                            handler.postDelayed(runnable, FADE_DURATION_MS);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private static void animateView(ImageView imageView, float fromAlpha, float toAlpha) {
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(fromAlpha, toAlpha);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animation.setDuration(FADE_DURATION_MS);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For change image old one to new one smoothly, use `withCrossFade`

```
DrawableCrossFadeFactory factory =
        new DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder().setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build();

GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .transition(withCrossFade(factory))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(R.color.placeholder)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to see old image fades then disappears that time new image is display. and if I use your code, it will give me color in while image change

Comment: by the way, what is this color `R.color.placeholder`? that color I add to them, right? I don't want show color, I want a image which displayed before

Comment: then how about save bitmap before change?
`Bitmap attachedbitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`
and use `attachedbitmap` in placeholder

Comment: And did you use Glide 4?
there is article in here. https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html

Comment: Yes, I did it, and same crash. and any way to set old image for placeholder?

Comment: then I think you have to use Glide 3.